# Using chatheads (Facebook messenger's "chat bubbles") for drag and drop within application

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm currently using an extremely simple and relatively ugly drag and drop with textviews in my application and am looking to improve it with something a little fancier/nicer to use. I really like the kinetics of  Facebook's [Chatheads](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/). I would like to replace my current drag and drop to instead use these chatheads (or some other bubble-like drag and drop library). This being said, **I only need the bubbles within my current fragment/activity**, so I do *not* want to require the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission (So that they are available on a device-wide context). **Is this possible with Chatheads/Is there another library that would be more suited for my goal?** Thanks guys!!

Comment: The tutorial you posted pretty much explains everything. What are you not able to do ?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out a way to create these bubbles without the system_alert_window permission. I want to create them in a single activity.  (As opposed to being laid above _all_ applications)